# Running Windows 7 on Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware

I want to run Windows 7 VM on Ubuntu in my machine and found a quite confusing problem.

My machine is an i5 with 8 GB ram (4GB x 2).

Both the Ubuntu and Windows 7 installations are 32-bit. In order to optimize the use of the ram, I want to give 4 GB RAM for each OS.

But is it possible that the two RAM are used for both OSes? That means each OS is allocated for 2GB of the two RAM. If yes, how could I do so? Any setting in the VMware?

Otherwise, is it possible to allocate each RAM for each OS only?

I am afraid that the machine will just use 1 RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The VM will only use as much RAM as it needs, just because you allocated 4 GB RAM to the VM does not mean it will all be used unless needed.

Think of it as the **maximum** RAM you want to allow the VM to use.

With 4 GB RAM allocated and 8 GB RAM on your machine it should work quite safely unless you are using lots of RAM on Ubuntu.

Comment: But can I enforce Ubuntu to use 2 GB of both ram?

Comment: What do you mean by 'use 2 GB of both RAM'?

Comment: I have 2 RAM. Each has 4GB.    I want to assign 2GB in ram 1 and 2GB in ram 2 to my Ubuntu. And I want to assign the 2GB left in each ram to my Window on the vmware

Comment: There is no need - or better, no way (as far as I can tell) - to assign '2 GB in RAM 1 and 2 GB in RAM 2'. 

Just assign 4 GB RAM to the Windows VM.